# If I created a widget, how can I set the width or height as screen ratio?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I created a widget, how can I set the width or height as screen ratio?

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network("http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg"),
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You see my upper code, I want the `width:Center_height` as `1:2`, how can I implement?
I mean the Center be carpeted with the screen page, the `Container's height : Center's height = 1:2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of directly passing value,
try using MediaQuery class.
Example

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

MediaQuery class will return the height / width of the current device, and you can directly use it accordingly, you can also use it like this,

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
```

here, widget will occupy the half width available in current screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Use** Mediaquery for`height` and `Width`

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

And implement like this

```
class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Image.network("http://a1.att.hudong.com/60/38/01200000194369136323385641912.jpg"),
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```